# ColorButton can not change text color Objective C

Tags: objective-c, xcode, tint

Since IOS 13 / xcode 11, I can not change the text color on my ColorButton objects using

```
ColorButton *b = [self addButtonToViewWithLabel:@"Press This" frame:[self getLGButtonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
b.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
b.tintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
```

It's in ViewWillAppear and the button is enabled but the text is always black.  Worked before under previous IOS.
Any ideas?

Comment: Can you show more of your code? What is b? Where is it defined? Without seeing more it's hard to diagnose why that one line of code may not be working.

Comment: I updated the code above.